# State of Binder#hasChanges() after user takes back changes

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

For an binder without a bound bean, the `hasChange()` method returns `true` as soon as a bound field is changed. But it's still `true` after the change gets reverted. So I'm looking for something like `isEqualToInitialState()`, in order to enable the save button for real changes only.

Is there a best practice for my intention? I also do not see a method like `hasChangesComparedTo(Bean bean)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Binder.hasChange` is just a "dumb" tracker, whether any value has
changed.  It has not concept of a "previous or original value".

If you want to compare the state of the binder with an original bean,
you would have to do that yourself:

0. (optional): add a proper equals method to your bean, so the
   comparison is easier to handle
1. keep the original value/bean and set a copy in the binder (e.g. use
   `readBean(orig)` and then `writeBean(empty)` to get the data into
   a fresh object)
2. Compare the original and the copy and then react accordingly